# How to remove white space using echo

Tags: linux, unix, echo

I am writing my code for creating cloud formation cluster with elastic search and kibana installed. i want to remove space using echo command and the IP-address should not be hard-coded.

```
SPARK_MASTER_IP=$(hostname -I)
echo $SPARK_MASTER_IP
10.100.53.254
"echo \"elasticsearch.url: \"http://$SPARK_MASTER_IP:9200\"\" | sudo tee -a /etc/kibana/kibana.yml\n",
```

The output of this command is as below, i see that there is space after the 
ip-address and before colon(**.254space:9200**) please help me how can i remove this space?

```
 elasticsearch: { url: 'http://10.100.53.254 :9200' } },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `${SPARK_MASTER_IP%% *}:9200` instead of `$SPARK_MASTER_IP`, which removes from the right the longest match of `" *"` (blank followed by anything).

Your shell manual has all the details how to remove various parts matching certain globs from the start and end of strings.

BTW, the `"` before `echo` and the comma at the end look broken. This is certainly not a valid shell command. What are you hiding from us?